# Proving a theorem about ordered lists

Tags: coq, proof

This should be a straight forward thing to prove, but I keep getting stuck.  Would be grateful for help...

```
Require Import Arith.

Fixpoint At n (l:list nat) :=
  match n with
    | 0    => match l with nil => None | cons x _  => Some x   end
    | S n' => match l with nil => None | cons _ l' => At n' l' end
  end.

Definition ordered l :=
  forall i j, i < j -> j < length l ->
              exists x y, At i l = Some x /\ At j l = Some y /\ x <= y.

Lemma ordered_cons:
  forall l a b, ordered (cons b l) -> a <= b ->  ordered (cons a (cons b l)).

  intros l a b H H0 i j Hij Hj.
  destruct i,j;
    (* solve three of the four cases, and leave one untouched *)
    try (inversion Hij; fail);
    try (apply H; simpl in *; omega).
```

EDIT: Here is the solution to finish the proof. I need to consider the two next cases for j.

```
  destruct j;
    try (exists a,b; auto; fail).

  destruct (H 0 (S j)) as [x [y [Ha [Hb Hc]]]]; auto with arith;
  simpl in *; inversion Ha; exists a, y;
  repeat split; try tauto; omega.
Qed.
```

Comment: Destructing i and j results in four cases, three are easily solved, but the one where i=0 and j=S j' is giving me trouble, but it should follow from the transitivity of <=.  But I end up with a proof case that can't be proved, so I must have lost some information somewhere.

Comment: Have you tried induction, instead of destruction?

Comment: I don't think that's necessary (but yes I've tried it).

Comment: Talking it through made me give it one more try. Thanks! :-)    I needed to consider the next two cases for j.  I've added the solution to the question.